# Will a person burn in hell fire forever even if he had faith but never followed Islam ?

Tags: sunni

If a person believes in Allah and Prophet Muhammad S.A.W and all the seven articles of faith in Islam but that person did what he desired and wanted despite the fact that he had faith but he did what he desired and wanted. So is that type of person also doomed ? Will there be any concession for this type of person ?

Comment: Such questions are unanswerable because we don't end up judging you, God does.

Comment: When Allah Himself answers a question, however, it is okay to share that answer with the questioner. That is what the Book of Allah was revealed for - to guide mankind out of the darkness of wrong thinking and sinful conduct. No one is require to guess about what is necessaryto attain salvation in the akhirah because Allah made it plain in His Book.

Comment: Consider these ayah, in addition to those I cited in my answer: “Truly, whoever comes to his Lord as a sinner - for him is Hell. In it he shall neither die nor live.” Qur‘an 20:74. Look these up also .... 4:107; 3:133-135 (esp. the end of 135); and 2:81-82. My point is that the Qur‘an is clear in stating that we can‘t insist on living contrary to the Guidance of Allah (which is the very definition of sinfulness) and still hope to be received in mercy on the Day of Judgment. To hold on to such hope is self delusion. It is better and wiser to just make tawbah and start living right.

Comment: @IbraheemMuhammad So does this mean a persons faith in Islam is useless if he does what he wants and desires ? Do you mean for that person there is no way out of hell fire then ?

Comment: I won‘t go so far as to say that someone‘s Imaan is 100% worthless. I read a hadith qudsee in An‘Nawawi‘s 40 Hadith Qudsee  where the Prophet (alaihi salaam) said that, on the Day of Judgment, Allahu ta alaa is going to allow him to pray for the members of his Ummah whose sinfulness landed them in Hell. The hadith said that Allah is going to grant the Prophet‘s prayer, GRADUALLY RELEASING PEOPLE BASED ON THE SIZE OF THE IMAAN IN THEIR HEARTS. Those with the smallest Imaan will end up staying in Hell the longest. But, Young Muslim 1000, Hellfire should be avoided, period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As‘salaamu alaikum.

We muslims are in this world to do the work  necessary to achieve salvation on the Day of Judgment. There is a basic criterion for the attainment of salvation:

(1) Imaan (faith); and

(2) Amil-us-Salihaat (good works).

To attain salvation you must have both.

Good works without correct Faith in Allah are worthless, because Allah has said that He is not going to give the good works of the Faithless any weight on the Day of Judgment.

> "Shall we tell you of those who will lose most in respect of their deeds? Those whose efforts have been wasted in this life, *WHILE THEY THOUGHT THEY WERE ACQUIRING GOOD BY THEIR WORKS?* They are those who deny the ayah  of their Lord and the fact of their having to meet Him. *VAIN WILL BE THEIR WORKS, NOR SHALL WE, ON  THE DAY OF JUDGMENT, GIVE THEM ANY WEIGHT*. That is their reward - Hell - *BECAUSE THEY REJECTED FAITH* and took My ayah and My Messengers as a joke."
>    **Al-Kahf 103-106**

On the other side of the same coin, having Faith but then failing to do any good deeds is also not enough to win anyone salvation.

> “Are they waiting to see if the angels come to them, or your Lord (Himself), or certain other signs of your Lord?! The Day that certain of the signs of your Lord do come, no good will it do a soul to believe in them then, if it didn‘t believe before, *NOR EARNED RIGHTEOUSNESS THROUGH ITS FAITH*.”
>   **Al-An'am 158**
>
> “Whoever works righteousness, man or woman, and has Faith, verily to them shall we give a new life, a life that is good and pure, and We will bestow on such their reward *ACCORDING TO THE BEST OF THEIR WORKS*.”
>   **Al-Nahl 97**

So that‘s it right there. It‘s not enough to merely say, “I believe”, because a pair of lips can SAY anything. Allah wants us to demonstrate that we mean what we say by putting work in for Him and His Deen.

Think about it: a “muslim” is one who submits to the Will of Allah. If a man never does anything that Allah has commanded  him to do, nor abstained from that which Allah told hin to stay away from, then that man is NOT one who submits - he is one who rebels (a faasiq).

Insha‘Allah, you will understand and be helped by this answer. Ma‘as‘salaam.